# How to change home page Featured Product - NopCommerce v3.30?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

**Problem**

**Category :** Computers >> Notebooks (`Is featured product?` Set as No)
But `HP Pavilion Artist Edition DV2890NR 14.1-Inch Laptop`  Under the `Category : Computers >> Notebooks`, display as featured product.

So until I unchecked the "**Published:**" option of "H**P Pavilion Artist Edition DV2890NR 14.1-Inch Laptop**" it was still showing as featured product.

I tried to stop display **default Feature product** in `Home Page`, and want to display `New Set of Products` as Feature Products ?

Unable to Understand How to do that from NopCommerce Admin Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the product from Featured Products on homepage uncheck "Show on home page" on the Product Info tab of the product edit page.